# How to format a numeric field in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, formatting

I want a numeric field to be always displayed as a 3-digit number. Padded left with 0s as needed.

Example: 3 is shown as 003, 24 as 024 and so on. Assuming max number is 999.

How do I do so? Thanks.

Comment: [Specify a custom format](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/specify-how-data-displays-by-using-custom-formatting-HA010334645.aspx).

Comment: The article cited by Robert Harvey suggests that formats be added to tables. For the most part, formats in tables are a very bad idea. Adding formats to forms and reports is fine: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/MSAccess/AccessVBAJetSQL/why-you-should-not-add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function Lpad (Value as String, PadCharacter as String, PaddedLength as Integer)
    Lpad = string(PaddedLength - Len(Value), PadCharacter) & Value
End Function
```

[Ref](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210573).

```
Lpad("3", "0", 3)
```