# How to specify a custom format for a text pattern in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access, formatting

I have a **text** column that is 1 or 2 characters long that contains only a number from 0 to 99.

What (text) format do I use to display it with a 0 prefix when it's only a one digit character?
This means '8' is displayed as '08' while 23 is left unchanged '23'.

I know how to do this when the field is **numeric** instead of text. All I need to do is putting 00 in the format field for this numeric column. Now I want to do the same when the field is text. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=Right("00" & someString,2)
```

No VBA required for such a simple thing.
You could use a format like "00" if the field was a number. with a string, using pure format, I am afraid there is no way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text format specification of the `TextBox` if you convert the value to a numeric value. In the `ControlSource` of the `TextBox` write:

```
=CLng(fieldName)
```

If your field can be `Null` this will produce an error and you will have to do this:

```
=IIf(IsNull(fieldName), Null, CLng(Nz(fieldName)))
```

The `Nz` is still required, as VBA always evaluates all three arguments of `IIf`.

Or if you want to display "00" if the field is `Null`, simply do this:

```
=CLng(Nz(fieldName))
```

---

When you use such expressions in TextBoxes or other Controls, make sure that the name of the Control is different than the name of the source column; otherwise you get an infinite recursion that produces an error. E.g. give the TextBox a name like "txtMyColumn" if the column name is "MyColumn".

Comment: Valid unless he wants to keep the expression as a string for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15456871/how-to-format-a-numeric-field-in-microsoft-access), create the following VBA function:

```
Function Lpad (MyValue as String, MyPadCharacter as String, _ 
           MyPaddedLength as Integer)
    Lpad = string(MyPaddedLength - Len(MyValue),MyPadCharacter) _
           & MyValue
End Function
```

To test this function, type the following line in the Immediate window, and then press ENTER:

```
?Lpad("123B","0",6)
```

ref: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210573

Comment: I voted up because this is another way to do what I want. However, my question is about how to do this using text format specification. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. Of course, if this is for a report then you could always use one of the suggested techniques (the one from @iDevlop is especially elegant) to output formatted text in the underlying query. That way you don't have to fiddle with format specifications in the report itself.